# Plotting using errorbar (same length error)

Tags: matlab, plot, std

This is probably a really basic question, but I have been working on it for a long time. I am trying to graph a matrix with error bars composed of the standard deviation. My matrix consists of time and corresponding data. I keep getting an error saying that X, Y and error bars must all be the same length. I have tested length(data) for each vector, and they are all the same.

I have:

```
s=std(data);
e = s*ones(length(data2));
errorbar(datenum(DateVector),data,e);
```

I really appreciate how helpful everyone on here is with my new-user questions. Thank you all!

Comment: Your `e` will be a square matrix, but I am guessing that `DateVector` and `data` will be vectors. Try replacing `ones(length(data2))` by `ones(length(data2),1)`.